# Will htmlspecialchars (php) be enough for making secure PDF files with user entered data?

Tags: php

My app creates an PDF file and uses an user entered info. How can I avoid all attacks with PDF vector?

Will htmlspecialchars be enough?

I don't want to enable JavaScript in PDF.

Comment: Hi. You'll need to provide more info as to what you are wanting to protect and how sensitive it is. You will never be able to avoid **all** attacks through a particular vector unless you remove the vector, so instead you need to look at **appropriate** controls and to answer this we need to know what your risk acceptance level is.

Comment: users will enter text data via web forms, then i will use this data for generating tables in PDF.

Answer (score 3):

How are you generating your PDFs? Unless you are creating HTML markup and using a tool to convert that to PDF, `htmlspecialchars` won't be of any use to you. `<` and `&` are not special in PDF text content.

If you are using the PHP PDFlib functions like `PDF_add_table_cell` to put your text in the document, there is no need for any particular kind of escaping. Those functions take raw text without any characters being 'special'. Other than general-purpose input filtering to remove unwanted control characters, no string preparation steps should be necessary.

I'm not sure what attacks you're trying to avoid; the most common problem with PDF is embedded scripting malware, but unless you're deliberately putting script in (using eg `PDF_create_action`) there won't be any in your produced document.

There was a global-XSS vulnerability in the browser PDF plugin once that affected any site hosting a PDF; if you want to ensure protection from that for users with old plugins you can serve all your PDFs with `Content-Disposition: attachment`.